# VSCodeVim: Switch tabs with `gt` when Jupyter notebook is active tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscodevim

**Summary**

When using Vim and Jupyter plugins in VSCode, how can I make the <kbd>gT</kbd>/<kbd>gt</kbd> commands cycle back/forth (the Vim default behavior) between open tabs when a Jupyter notebook is the active tab?

**Detail**

When editing most text files in VSCode using the VSCodeVim plugin, I can use the classic Vim command <kbd>gT</kbd>/<kbd>gt</kbd> to cycle back/forth between open tabs.

In the special case of Jupyter notebooks with the Jupyter plugin, these are rendered JSON documents comprising nested "cells" which complicates normal Vim-style navigation. When I cycle through tabs to a Jupyter notebook, the <kbd>gt</kbd> binding ceases to function, and I get "The key combination (G, T) is not a command" in the status bar.

**EDIT:** <kbd>gT</kbd>/<kbd>gt</kbd> *does* switch between tabs when I am within a Jupyter notebook *and* editing a cell. But when switching to a Jupyter notebook not in the cell-editing state (i.e. focus is at the notebook level), <kbd>gT</kbd>/<kbd>gt</kbd> ceases to work. I suppose since we are no longer in a text-editing mode, the Vim keybindings are not active.

Is there a way I can map/enable the Vim-style tab-switching behavior for the "notebook" level as well, when a Jupyter notebook is the active tab?

**Versions**

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| MacOS | 13.6.3 |
| VSCode | 1.87.0 |
| Jupyter Extension | v2024.2.0 |
| Vim Extension | v1.27.2 |

Comment: [you might not be alone](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/7635#issuecomment-1755522323), but I **cannot repro**. works fine for me on Windows 11, VS Code 1.87.1, VS Code Vim 1.27.2. Please add your version info to your question post, and try to repro with a new temporary [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post with version info, and I've reproduced it from a new profile after installing Jupyter and Vim extensions. I can switch tabs using `gt`/`gT` when the active tab is not a Jupyter Notebook but when I land on an open Jupyter Notebook, I get the status bar message described above and cannot continue cycling through tabs using those keys.

Comment: interesting. do you have a windows or linux machine you can test on? or a friend/colleague with one that you can ask to try to repro on their machine?

Comment: Please see my edits, `gT`/`gt` does work, but only if you're editing a cell. If no cell is being edited (i.e. focus is at the 'notebook' level), Vim-style tab switching is not mapped. If you switch tabs while editing a cell in a Jupyter notebook, when you switch back the notebook will still be in that state--so you can cycle through tabs as expected. But if any of your tabs is a notebook with focus at the 'notebook' level, `gT`/`gt` tab switching breaks.